# How to remove an element from a Set inside a Page of items based on a Condition using Java 8

Tags: java, jpa, collections, java-8, stream

I have a `Page` of `Farmers` coming from a **JPA repository** call `findAll` method. Each Farmer consists of a `Set` of `Farms` which are also coming in the repository call like so:

```
public class Farmer {

private String name;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "farmer_asset", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "farmer_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "asset_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<Asset> assets;
}
```

`Asset` has a property called `isActive` which indicates that the asset is active or not;

In my `Page` of `Farmers` I want to select only farmers' Assets which are active;

I tried with
`@WhereJoinTable(clause = "is_active ='true'")`

However, I learnt that the `is_active` property is supposed to be in the intermediate ManyToMany relation Table `farmer_asset`

Now I am not in a position to change the entity structure, and use `@WhereJoinTable(clause = "is_active ='true'")`.

So, I thought of trying to filter the values after making the JPA call.

However, iterating through each `Farmer`, then removing the `inActive Assets` and then adding it back to the Page and maintaining Page elements seemed too performance heavy operation.

I tried with normal Java Code which looks something like this:

```
Page<Farmer> farmers = farmerRepository.findAll(pageable);

List<Farmer> farmersList = new LinkedList<>();

for (FarmerDto eachFarmer : farmers.getContent()) {

   Set<Asset> eachFarmerAssets = 
   eachFarmer.getAssets();

   eachFarmerAssets.removeIf(e -> 
   !e.getIsActive());

   eachFarmer.setAssets(eachFarmerAssets);              
   
   farmersList.add(eachFarmer);
               }
         return new PageImpl<FarmerDto>(farmersList, pageable, farmers.getTotalElements());
```

I would like to do this is Java 8 using streams but I am not able to iterate a list and change its element which is in turn a `Set<Asset>`

Came here looking for some suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't to reassign the same reference to `Set<Asset>` because even the set has been modified, it's still the same object which is "known" to a particular farmer.

And definitely you don't need streams for this task. Documentation suggests avoiding stateful operations and side-effects while designing stream pipe-lines.

Instead, you can use `forEach()` method on a list:

```
Page<Farmer> farmers = farmerRepository.findAll(pageable);
List<Farmer> farmersList = new farmers.getContent();
    
farmersList.forEach(farmer -> farmer.getAssets()
    .removeIf(e -> !e.getIsActive()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, the forEach worked as expected, I didn't have to use extra lists to store the filtered output.

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow these steps:

1. retrieve the list of farmer entities
2. transform the list of entities to the list of farmer dtos
3. for each farmer dto

   1. fill the data
   2. put the list of assert that are active

```java
List<Farmer> farmers = farmerRepository.findAll(pageable).getContent(); //1
List<FarmerDto> farmersList = farmers.stream() // 2
        .map(farmer -> { // 3
            FarmerDto farmerDto = new FarmerDto();
            // fill farmerDto 3.1
            farmerDto.setAssets(farmer.getAssets().stream().filter(Farmer::getIsActive()).toList()); //3.2
            return farmerDto;
        }).toList();
return new PageImpl<FarmerDto>(farmersList, pageable, farmers.getTotalElements());
```